# Python: String indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on some Python code to automate github merge requests.

I found the following code below.  When I run this, I get TypeError: string indices must be integers.

I've found several threads on here refrencing this error, but I'm not quit sure how to implement the fixes in the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import requests
import datetime


OAUTH_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
repos = ['my_app'] # Add all repo's you want to automerged here
ignore_branches = ['master', 'release', 'staging', 'development'] # Add 'master' here if you don't want to automerge into master


# Print merge/no-merge message to logfile
def print_message(merging):
  if merging == True:
   message = "Merging: "
 else:
  message = "Not merging: "
 print message + str(pr_id) + " - " + user + " wants to merge " + head_ref + " into " + base_ref


# Merge the actual pull request
def merge_pr():
  r = requests.put("https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/%s/pulls/%d/merge"%(repo,pr_id,),
   data=json.dumps({"commit_message": "Auto_Merge"}),
   auth=('token', OAUTH_KEY))
  if "merged" in r.json() and r.json()["merged"]==True:
   print "Merged: " + r.json()['sha']
  else:
   print "Failed: " + r.json()['message']


# Main

print datetime.datetime.now()

for repo in repos:
  r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/%s/pulls' % repo, auth=('token', OAUTH_KEY))
  data = r.json()

for i in data:
  head_ref=i["head"]["ref"]
  base_ref=i["base"]["ref"]
  user=i["user"]["login"]
  pr_id = i["number"]
  if base_ref in ignore_branches:
   print_message(False)
  else:
   print_message(True)
   merge_pr()
```

Comment: What did the threads you found say about it? Can you reproduce by shortening the code? What's the full error message (stack trace and line numbers included, after shortening down to a minimum reproducible example). Please edit those details into the question, rather than commenting. (Feel free to comment that you've done so if you want me to take a look when you're done.)

Comment: can you print "data", the result of r.json() ?  My guess is that you're trying to access a dict like it was a list.

Comment: On what line did the error arise?

Comment: line 41, in <module>
 head_ref=i["head"]["ref"]

Comment: most likely your error is arising in the `for i in data block`, either `i` is a string, or one of the value from `i["head"]`, `i["base"]` are returning a string. Would help if you posted contents of `data`

Comment: Contents of data:
{u'documentation_url': u'https://developer.github.com/v3', u'message': u'Not Found'}

Comment: Ok, I think I found my issue, it looks like I had permissions issue with my token, thus the string being returned instead of the integer for the completed operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which line of code is showing a problem?
if it is this line:

```js
'else:
  message = "Not merging: "
 print message + str(pr_id) + " - " + user + " wants to merge " + head_ref + " into " + base_ref'
```

then try putting this code right below

```js
if merging == True:
  message = "Merging: "
```

:

```
elif message == False:
  message = "Not merging: "
print message + pr_id + " - " + user + " wants to merge " + head_ref + " into " + base_ref ''
```

Comment: I was not authenticating properly, thus bad data was returning.  I have now solved my problem.

Comment: Snippets should only be used for HTML/CSS/JavaScript at present. Use ordinary code blocks for Python.